# How to expose more than one source log file for a pod in Sitecore in AKS

Tags: logging, kubernetes, aks

We are in the process of upgrading to Sitecore 10.1 and we are also changing our infrastructure to use AKS.

I just noticed the the Sitecore logs we get from the pods seems to only include the logs sent through the LogFileAppender (in other words, we only see the logs from the **log.{date}.{time}.txt** files).

We have some modules that are by default configured to log in their own files (for example Dianoga or Sitecron). When inspecting the pods, I can see their log files on disk, but the content of these files does not show in the pods logs (that we can get using the *kubectl logs ${POD_NAME}*  command or using a tool like k9s).

By changing these modules configuration so that they use the LogFileAppender works. More precisely, this works

```
    <logger name="Sitecron" role:require="ContentManagement">
        <appender-ref ref="SitecronLogFileAppender">
            <patch:delete />
        </appender-ref>
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
```

**but I was wondering if there is way of doing this at the pod level (or in a more Kubernetes native way).** For example, if I could change the way Sitecore configures the pods to also include some other log files would be great.

I hope my question is clear enough! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LogMonitor.exe` application that is included in the Sitecore images and stored in the `C:\LogMonitor` folder is a Microsoft logging tool for Windows containers. This application is responsible to monitor configured log sources and to pipe a formatted output to `SDTOUT` output location.

The tool configuration is defined in the `C:\LogMonitor\LogMonitorConfig.json` file. This is the default configuration taken from the `sitecore-xp0-cm:10.1.1` image:

```
{
    "LogConfig": {
      "sources": [
        {
          "type": "EventLog",
          "startAtOldestRecord": false,
          "eventFormatMultiLine": false,
          "channels": [
            {
              "name": "system",
              "level": "Error"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "File",
          "directory": "c:\\inetpub\\logs",
          "filter": "*.log",
          "includeSubdirectories": true
        },
        {
          "type": "File",
          "directory": "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_data\\logs",
          "filter": "log.*.txt",
          "includeSubdirectories": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You need to add your own source in this configuration or modify the filter of the third source in the default configuration (filter value is `"log.*.txt"`), currently including only `.txt` files with a filename that starts with `log.`, in order to include additional logging files with a different name pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I brought a copy of this file in our source code, modified it and then copied it back during our custom Sitecore image creation process and it works. Found this link presenting the LogMonitor tool if anyone else is interested : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/windows-containers-log-monitor-opensource-release/ba-p/973947